# How to access a two dimensional array value and assing value to a int in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with my two dimensional array in C. Say 2D array is `board[d][d]` (`d=7`) and i want to assign value of `board[d-1][d-2]` to an `int`. When i do this i get error, if i printf `board[d-1][d-2]` i get `32766`. The highest value in the array is `d*d-1=48`. 
What am i doing wrong?

```
int main(void)
{
   int d=7;
   int nr=(d*d)-1;
   int board[d][d];
   int u=board[d-1][d-2];
   bool even=false;
   if ((d/2)*2!=d)
   {
      even=true;
   }
   printf("%d\n", even);

   printf("%i\n", board[d-1][d-2]); //result here is 32764?

   for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
   {
      for(int j=0;j<d;j++)
      {
         board[i][j]=nr;
         nr--;
         printf(" %2d", board[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you didn't initialize it with any value, so it simply stores whatever garbage happened to be there in memory atm.
You need to run on board and set initial values to it.

Comment: I put the int u after the for loop so now its initialised, thanks for help.

Comment: @lkoks an upvote an answer acceptance are stackoverflow way to say thanks :) Good luck in your coding efforts!

Comment: What is garbage in memory?

Comment: Random values that are unpredictable and should be disposed of.

Comment: Unpredictable how?

Comment: Each time you run, it can be a different value and you can't know which in advance.

Comment: If by valid you mean the program won't crash, yes. I fail to see why would you want to read an unitialized thing.

Comment: reading from an uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour. The program can crash there (and will crash on some architectures).

Comment: @IvanRubinson As mch said.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the `board` array it's not initalised - you get garbage values inside. A good practice is to initialise the array before using it

```
int board[d][d] = {0};
```

If you move `printf` after the loop where you fill the array with values, you'll get the expected result

Comment: I get a error trying to initialise it;"error: variable-sized object may not be initialized".

Comment: @lkoks either use `const int d = 7`, or `memset(board,0,d*d*sizeof(int))` to zero it out.

Comment: I put the int u after the for loop so now its initialised, thanks for help.

Comment: @lkoks an upvote an answer acceptance are stackoverflow way to say thanks :) Good luck in your coding efforts!

Comment: What are garbage values?

Comment: @2501 they're the values that were there in memory when a block of it was allocated for your needs. Compiler doesn't initialize it to any value for efficiency reasons

Comment: C doesn't really define what 'garbage' is. I think you should be clearer. The answer is implying that reading 'garbage' is valid, because you say it is good practice to initialize but it isn't necessary. In reality it is undefined behavior, and not just not good practice.

Comment: @2501 I wrote that initializing the array before using it is a good practice

Comment: So I can read the values without initializing and my program will be correct, except it won't be good practice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115839/discussion-between-buld0zzr-and-2501).

Comment: @2501 this is really a long discussion you're trying to start :) I agree that a good advice for all programmers, especially of novice level, is to always initialize everything you create

Comment: It is really simple actually. It is undefined behavior: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior , and defined in the Standard.